# Removing duplicated elements from an array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have two numpy arrays:

```
[  2.09588161   2.34243927   2.45505059   3.61549894   6.42506932
   8.52095092   5.76933731   6.03952746   4.30033044   3.77862927
   3.73546847   5.40022069   8.52095092  10.61683253   7.75964201
   8.01668568   6.17414768   4.40489563   4.72554455   5.76933731
   7.75964201   6.02187958   4.53771075   2.59319536   1.94766573
   6.03952746   8.01668568   4.53771075   6.6124742    5.38450762
   4.30033044   6.17414768   2.59319536   5.38450762   4.67416659
   2.09588161   2.34243927   2.45505059   3.61549894   3.77862927
   3.73546847   5.40022069   4.40489563   4.72554455   1.94766573]

[ 2.09588161  2.34243927  2.45505059  3.61549894  3.77862927  3.73546847
  5.40022069  4.40489563  4.72554455  1.94766573]
```

How can I remove elements from the first array that are the same like in the second one.

I have seen the uniques method, but it removes only duplicated elements from a particular array.

Comment: how large is a dataset? I mean if it is a matter of 1k items - just use sets, otherwise you would have to explore numpy

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suspect you desire [numpy.setdiff1d](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.setdiff1d.html)

> numpy.setdiff1d(ar1, ar2, assume_unique=False)[source]¶ Find the set
>   difference of two arrays.
>
> Return the sorted, unique values in ar1 that are not in ar2.